# Java7 Update21 Applet Issue

Tags: java, applet, nullpointerexception, java-7

I am facing the Issue while running the application with Applets,Could some one please help me regarding this Issue.

I am running in IE8 and Java7Update21,Could some one help this Issue.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-15" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.checkUntrustedAccess(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo.isLiveconnectCallAllowed(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo.doObjectOp(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport.doObjectOp(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.MessagePassingJSObject.waitForReply(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.MessagePassingJSObject.call(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Could you please provide complete Exception details? if possible the applet log.

Comment: You need to provide more information.  This question is unanswerable in its current form.  (That's why it got closed last time!)

Comment: Is the applet signed? If yes, with a selfsigned certificate or a certificate from an trusted authority. Is the applet developed by you? If not, ask the developer of the applet for support. There have been some changes concerning applets in the security domain with the last Java updates (7update21 and 7update25)

Answer (score 0):

The issue stated above only occurs when the applet calls a javascript function which in turn makes a call to the applet. For example the applet calls a success javascript callback method which makes some GUI stuff in the browser and then calls the applet so that the applet can prepare for the next processing.